Why is an intarray operator not available when the query is called using PDO?
PostgreSQL version 14
I have a query behaving differently when run from pgAdmin than it does when run from PHP.
SELECT * FROM UNNEST('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[] - '{2,4}'::integer[])

When I run this from pgAdmin, it works fine. When I pass it in through PHP using PDO, I get
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer[] - integer[].
This array operator is provided by the intarray module. CREATE EXTENSION intarray tells me that the extension is already installed. It's like the intarray module isn't available to the PHP process for some reason.
Can anyone point me in the right direction re what might be going on here?

Best guess the database you are connecting to with the  PHP code is not the same one you are connecting to in pgAdmin4. Verify by checking the Postgres log.

Where is the php code that causes error?

Might be a limitation of PDO vs the pg_* driver.

@AdrianKlaver: Same database, but different user. One with fewer permissions. I'll try running as that user and see if I can replicate.
u_mulder: This code has been working fine for years. Only this situation is a problem, so I don''t think it's a general issue with the PHP unless, as Alex Howansky suggests, it's a quirk of PDO.

I tried making the user a superuser. No change.

The error is pretty specific the issue is with the - operator for arrays,  which is provided by intarray. I don't see how it could be anything other then that intarray is not installed or it is inaccessible. In psql what does \dx return for extension. Also check the Postgres log for more information.

My bet would be that intarray's installed, just into a namespace that's not shown in your search_path/current_schema(true) when you run your tests from the PHP app. You can check where it is and either add the schema to the search path or add schema qualification of the operator with operator().

See this fiddle.

@Zegarek: BINGO!!! intarray is in public and there is code explicitly setting the search path to a specific schema without including public. Please post this as the answer so I can accept it.

As per @Adrian Klaver's comment, it's good to first confirm your PHP app and the client you were running the tests with, both connect to one and the same cluster and on it, the same database that does have intarray installed. Multiple instances running on the same host or behind tunnels set up on it, typos in database name or port number could all obfuscate the fact that you're dealing with distinct, mismatched DBs.
Since you could confirm that's not the case, my bet would be that intarray is installed, just into a namespace that's not shown in your search_path/current_schemas(true) when you run your tests from the PHP app.
You can check where it is: demo at db<>fiddle
create schema some_other_schema;
create extension intarray schema some_other_schema;
select extname,extnamespace::regnamespace from pg_extension;




extname
extnamespace




plpgsql
pg_catalog


intarray
some_other_schema



select e.extnamespace::regnamespace
     , p.oprnamespace::regnamespace
     , e.extname
     , p.oid::regoperator
     , p.oprname
     , p.oprcode::regprocedure
from pg_catalog.pg_operator as p
join pg_catalog.pg_depend    as d on (d.objid    = p.oid)
join pg_catalog.pg_extension as e on (d.refobjid = e.oid)
where e.extname='intarray'
  and p.oprname='-';




extnamespace
oprnamespace
extname
oid
oprname
oprcode




some_other_schema
some_other_schema
intarray
some_other_schema.-(integer[],integer)
-
some_other_schema.intarray_del_elem(integer[],integer)


some_other_schema
some_other_schema
intarray
some_other_schema.-(integer[],integer[])
-
some_other_schema.intset_subtract(integer[],integer[])



Once you're sure where it is, add schema qualification of the operator with operator():
select array[1,2] operator(some_other_schema.-) array[2,3];

Or add the schema to search_path:
select set_config( 'search_path'
                  ,'some_other_schema, '
                   ||current_setting('search_path')
                  ,false);

Which lets you skip the operator's schema qualification:
select array[1,2] - array[2,3];


It's worth pointing out that contrary to what the extension name would suggest, intarray's int[] - int[] subtracts sets, not arrays. Both operands will be sorted and deduplicated prior to the subtraction. It's a bit clearer when you check that the - variant subtracting whole other int[] is called intset_subtract while the one subtracting a single element is called intarray_del_elem and it doesn't do the silent uniq(sort()).

This answer solved my problem. intarray is installed in public and my search path in PHP did not include public. Thank you!!!!
